# How to convert .slk files to .txt or .xlsx files in ETL process using Talend

Tags: etl, xlsx, talend, slk

I need to convert .slk files into .txt or .xlsx formate to process the data contained in the .slk files during ETL(Extraction Transformation and Loading) through TALEND Studio. I was able to convert it to .txt formate using tChangeFileEncode component of the TALEND STUDIO but .txt file has more number of rows than .slk file.

Comment: could you please show us how the .slk file contents look like.

Comment: i am able to open the file using excel sheet and it contains a databse table 's data